# Time intelligence measures disappearing depending on filter selection. Why?

Tags: powerbi, data-analysis, powerbi-desktop, measure

I have the following Measure:

```
Events = COUNTROWS('Event Data')
```

Custom columns in a Date table:

```
DatesWithEvents = 'Date Dimension'[Date] <= MAX('Event Data'[DOE])

ExcludeFutureDates = 'Date Dimension'[Date] <= TODAY()
enter code here
```

The following Calculated items either appear or disappear from the visual depending on selections on the two filters above. Why is this?

Calculation items inside Calculation groups:
YTD: CALCULATE ( SELECTEDMEASURE (), DATESYTD ( 'Date Dimension'[Date] ) )
MTD: CALCULATE ( SELECTEDMEASURE (), DATESMTD ( 'Date Dimension'[Date] ) )
Rolling 12 2: CALCULATE(
SELECTEDMEASURE (),
DATESINPERIOD('Date Dimension'[Date], MAX('Date Dimension'[Date]), -12, MONTH)
)

I would like to exclude any events that are in the future. Eg. for MTD results I would like to include events where the date is between 1 June and today's date. I'd like to exclude any future dates. Which of the two custom column above will give me this result?

Also, why am I getting different "Rolling 12 2" results in scenarios 1 and 3? YTD and MTD are the same, but Rolling 12 2 is different. Why might this be the case?

[image: Three different results depending on filter selections]

Comment: I'm now using the following measure to calculate Rolling 12 months. But it isn't returning the correct result. Any idea what is wrong with it? I'd like the rolling 12 month period to end on the last day of the previous month.

CALCULATE(
    SELECTEDMEASURE (),
    FILTER(
        ALL('Date Dimension'[Date]),
        'Date Dimension'[Date] >= EDATE(MAX('Date Dimension'[Date]), -12) &&
        'Date Dimension'[Date] <= EOMONTH(TODAY(), -1)
    )
)

Comment: I resolved the Rolling 12 months issue by using the following calc
CALCULATE(
    SELECTEDMEASURE (),
    FILTER(
        ALL('Date Dimension'[Date]),
        'Date Dimension'[Date] >= DATE(YEAR(EDATE(TODAY(), -12)), MONTH(EDATE(TODAY(), -12)), 1) &&
        'Date Dimension'[Date] <= EOMONTH(TODAY(), -1)
    )
)

Comment: However, I can still not work out why the calculation items keep disappearing when I deselect the filters, and also which of the filters is the correct one... Any help would be appreciated